# How does Verilog unroll nested for loops?

Tags: for-loop, verilog, fpga

I am trying to do a cummulative sum with a series of nested for loops and am having no luck.  I think I need a better understanding of how Verilog unrolls the for loops before I can really visualize how to solve my problem.

Essentially I have a series of tap outputs (tap_output_i and tap_output_q) that are 3D arrays (src, dst, tap).  I want to sum all the source and taps going to a particular destination each clock.

Here is what I have that does not work (out_sig is 0 every time):

```
//NODES = 2
wire signed [DAC_BUS_WIDTH-1:0]      out_sig_i [NODES-1:0];
wire signed [DAC_BUS_WIDTH-1:0]      out_sig_q [NODES-1:0];
reg signed [DAC_BUS_WIDTH-1:0] out_sig_i_reg[NODES-1:0];
reg signed [DAC_BUS_WIDTH-1:0] out_sig_q_reg[NODES-1:0];

integer dstVal,srcVal, tapVal;
//generate
always @(posedge clk) begin: AlwaysSummingForLoop
  for (dstVal=0; dstVal<2; dstVal=dstVal+1) begin:SummingForLoop
    out_sig_i_reg[dstVal] <= 0;
    out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= 0;
      for (srcVal=0; srcVal<2; srcVal=srcVal+1) begin:SrcForLoop
        if(srcVal != dstVal) begin:innerIf
             for (tapVal=0; tapVal<8; tapVal=tapVal+1) begin:tapSum
                out_sig_i_reg[dstVal] <= out_sig_i_reg[dstVal] + tap_output_i[srcVal][dstVal][tapVal];
                out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] + tap_output_q[srcVal][dstVal][tapVal];
             end
        end
      end
    end
end
//endgenerate
assign out_sig_i[0] = out_sig_i_reg[0];
assign out_sig_q[0] = out_sig_q_reg[0];
assign out_sig_i[1] = out_sig_i_reg[1];
assign out_sig_q[1] = out_sig_q_reg[1];
```

Where I am running into issues is resetting the cumulative (`out_sig_i_reg` and `out_sig_q_reg`) sum every count...

Comment: Yes, I am using out_sig_i_reg and out_sig_q_reg as my cummultive sum. What I can't figure out is how to get it to cumulatively sum AND reset to zero each time before the summing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<=` is a non-blocking assignment. That is it makes a temporary copy of the righthand side carries on procedurally (non-blocking) executing the code for this timestep then makes the assignment from the temp variable to the left hand side. It is used to model the simulation of flip-flop behaviour.

A flip-flop can only change value once per clock cycle.

You have (simplified code):

```
out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= 0;
for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin
  for (j=0; j<8; j=j+1) begin
    out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] + tap_output_q[i][dstVal][j];
  end
end
```

In the above code `out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= 0;` will never take effect it is always overridden by the next statement; `out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] ...`

Your for loop repeatedly uses the same left hand side, but only the last assignment will win. For a given register only one `<=` per clockcycle can be effective. Effective for-loops would need to change the inner most left-hand register.

You could create a combinatorial block which describes the iteration using `=` and then put it through one flip-flop at the end.

```
always @* begin
   //..
   out_sig_q[dstVal] = 0;
   for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin
     for (j=0; j<8; j=j+1) begin
       out_sig_q[dstVal] = out_sig_q[dstVal] + tap_output_q[i][dstVal][j];
     end
   end
   //..
 end

always (@posedge clk) begin 
  for ...
    out_sig_q_reg[dstVal] <= out_sig_q[dstVal];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So are you putting both of those always blocks within a single larger: for (dstVal=0; dstVal<2; dstVal=dstVal+1) ?

Comment: @toozie21 No, you will have to put that inside each always block. It is not common to have always inside for, as that becomes a generate for-loop. I added the `//..` as a cryptic guide for you to fillin the loop details.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to like it. I have "always @* begin" followed by "for (dstVal=0; dstVal<2; dstVal=dstVal+1)" followed by "out_sig_q[dstVal] = 0;". but that throws a "Procedural assignment to a non-register out_sig_q is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar" error.

Comment: @toozie21 `out_sig_q` would also need to be declared as a reg type, but it is not a flip-flop.

Comment: use reg for `always`,`initial`. wire for `assign` and connecting instance outputs.